# Wait until ajax request is done before each() jquery continue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using Jquery ajax to check registration form.

this is my code:

```
            $("input.register_input").each(function()   {
                name= this.name;
                $(".ono#"+name).html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
                if (name == 're_password')  {
                    var dts =  this.name+"="+$(this).val()+"&pass="+$("input[name='password']").val();
                }   else    {
                    var dts =  this.name+"="+$(this).val();
                }
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajc/register_check.php",
                    data: dts,
                    success: function(resultfrompage){ 
                        $(".ono#"+name).html(resultfrompage);
                        }
                });
            });
```

This is after user submitting the form. so I can't check all values at once.

I dont completly sure if that's the problem, but I this the `each()` loop is running before the ajax request is done so I'm getting only 1 value (last one) back. and all the rest still showing `ajax-loader.gif`.

This is the reason for the problem? and if so how can I fix it?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try t use [async:false](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

> By default, all requests are sent asynchronously (i.e. this is set to
>   true by default). If you need synchronous requests, set this option to
>   false. Cross-domain requests and dataType: "jsonp" requests do not
>   support synchronous operation. Note that synchronous requests may
>   temporarily lock the browser, disabling any actions while the request
>   is active. As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false with jqXHR
>   ($.Deferred) is deprecated; you must use the success/error/complete
>   callback options instead of the corresponding methods of the jqXHR
>   object such as jqXHR.done() or the deprecated jqXHR.success().

```
$("input.register_input").each(function()   {
            name= this.name;
            $(".ono#"+name).html("<img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'>");
            if (name == 're_password')  {
                var dts =  this.name+"="+$(this).val()+"&pass="+$("input[name='password']").val();
            }   else    {
                var dts =  this.name+"="+$(this).val();
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: false,
                url: "ajc/register_check.php",
                data: dts,
                success: function(resultfrompage){ 
                    $(".ono#"+name).html(resultfrompage);
                    }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Thx! it's working great. But I didn't understand what you said about jquery 1.8+

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case

Comment: @alexeypalamar here you can find the documentation, go to async option documentation and read whats in bold. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to show some loading image while the Ajax request is processed. This way the user will understand that something is going on in the background. When this process will be finished handle the response.

Comment: can you please show me an example? How can I show image while the ajax is loading? and this will make the `each()` loop wait for the ajax request to finish?